# Pandas filling blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.3.4

So here's the df:

```
1   First name  Last Name
2   Freddie     Mercury
3   John        Lennon
4   David       Bowie
5   
6   Joseph
7               Jovi
```

I'm trying to fill the blank line (5) with "John Doe" when I concat `First name` and `Last name` but I do not want to put a "John Doe" in line 6 or 7 as it has a partial name.

So this is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str, header=0)
df['First name'] = df['First name'].str.replace(' ', 'John Doe', regex=True)
df['Last name'] = df['Last name'].str.replace(' ', 'John Doe', regex=True)
df['fullname'] = df['First name'].fillna(" ") + " " + df["Last name"].fillna(" ")


df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

This currently produces a `fullname` column which looks like:

```
fullname
Freddie Mercury
John Lennon
David Bowie

Joseph
Jovi
```

This is what I want:

```
Freddie Mercury
John Lennon
David Bowie
John Doe
Joseph
Jovi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['fullname'] = (df[['First name', 'Last Name']]
   .fillna('').agg(' '.join, axis=1)        # replace nan with '' and concatenate
   .str.strip()                             # remove leading/trailing spaces
   .replace('', 'John Doe')                 # replace empty name with default
)
```

Output:

```
  First name Last Name         fullname
0    Freddie   Mercury  Freddie Mercury
1       John    Lennon      John Lennon
2      David     Bowie      David Bowie
3       None      None         John Doe
4     Joseph      None           Joseph
5        NaN      Jovi             Jovi
```